# implementing nested linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nested-lists

Is this kind of implementation of nested linked list valid in c++?
if yes,then how to declare a head to those nested linked lists?
what is the syntax for accessing the data in those lists inside?
here is a part of my general code.
I'm trying to perform a library management system in c++.

```
     struct course
     { 
         string course_name;
            struct course_books
              {
                 struct wait_list
                  {
                   long stu_num;
                   //date inserted
                   wait_list * next_wait_stu;
                  };
                 struct voters_list
                  {
                   long stu_num;
                   int vote;
                   voters_list * next_voter;

                  };
                  struct deposit_list
                   {
                  long stu_num;
                    //date given
                    //bring back date
                  deposit_list * next_depositor;
                   };
            };
         course * next_course;

          };


             struct demand
              {
                 int ISBN;
                 string book_name,
                           course,
                           author,
                          edition;
                 int demands_num;
                struct demanding_students
                  {
                  string demander_name;
                  int demander_stu_number;
                   //demand date
                  demanding_students * next_demanding_stu;
                      };
              demand * next_demand;

                };

      struct STUDENT_INFO
       {
           struct all_deposited_books
              {
                int ISBN;
                //date given
                //bring back date
                all_deposited_books * next_dep_book;
                  };
             struct today_deposited
               {
                int ISBN;
                 today_deposited * next_today_dep_book;
                };
             };
```

Comment: do you have some problems running it, or what is the reason this question arised?

Comment: @GoogleHireMe i wonder if this is possible.if yes,then how shuold i access inner lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to use classes for this instead. Something like:

```
    class STUDENT_INFO{
        protected:
          struct all_deposited_books
          {
            int ISBN;
            //date given
            //bring back date

          };
          struct today_deposited
          {
            int ISBN;

          };
        public:
          all_deposited_books * next_dep_book;
          today_deposited * next_today_dep_book;
    };
```

Then you create a class instance like: `STUDENT_INFO theBestStudentInfo;` and if you want to accses a struct variable inside that you just call: `theBestStudentInfo.all_deposited_books[0].ISBN = 5;` or something like that.
Aswell as I dont think you can create a struct instance inside the struct itself, like:

```
struct all_deposited_books
   {
            int ISBN;
            //date given
            //bring back date
            all_deposited_books * next_dep_book; //<- this is probably gonna cause problems
   };
```

first create the struct and how its going to look like, and then you can start creating how many instances of it as you want :)

Comment: Classes are generally better to use when dealing with bigger stuff.